# swipebox auto transition to next slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

This is more of a tip than a question, but i hope others find this useful.

Basically i needed to make the lightbox slider called 'Swipebox' auto transition to the next slide, I looked online for help but found nothing.

to add this feature to the plugin i added this code:

```
setInterval(function(){

     $this.getNext();  // Auto transitions each slide

}, 5000);
```

The file for this JS is called 'jquery.swipebox.js'. This is the code where you want to place the code previously mentioned:

```
/**
         * Navigation events : go to next slide, go to prevous slide and close
         */
        actions : function () {
            var $this = this,
                action = 'touchend click'; // Just detect for both event types to allow for multi-input

            if ( elements.length < 2 ) {

                $( '#swipebox-bottom-bar' ).hide();

                if ( undefined === elements[ 1 ] ) {
                    $( '#swipebox-top-bar' ).hide();
                }

            } else {
                $( '#swipebox-prev' ).bind( action, function( event ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    $this.getPrev();
                    $this.setTimeout();
                } );

                $( '#swipebox-next' ).bind( action, function( event ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    $this.getNext();
                    $this.setTimeout();
                } );
            }

            $( '#swipebox-close' ).bind( action, function() {
                $this.closeSlide();
            } );


// THIS IS THE NEW CODE ADDED:

            setInterval(function(){

                $this.getNext();  // Auto transitions each slide

            }, 5000);
        },
```

This function is around about 550 lines down.

Also, to make the slideshow loop back around, you will need to change the option called 'loopAtEnd' from FALSE to TRUE. This is located at the top of the document.

```
loopAtEnd: true,
```

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Just found a problem... Turns out this code will run twice for some reason??  Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Did you ever figure the double code problem? I need to do the same thing.